# Problem installing Ubuntu 14.04 server on a powerPC (IBM power5 eserver)

Tags: server, system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu-14.04-server-powerpc on my IBM power5 eserver (p5 type 9117-570). I can only connect to this server using a serial connection (it does not have a video card). I tried to install Ubuntu from the CD using the boot command:

```
install-powerpc64 console=ttyS0
```

but it hangs. Here is the output:

```
Please wait, loading kernel...
   Elf64 kernel loaded...
Loading ramdisk...
ramdisk loaded at 03600000, size: 8412 Kbytes
OF stdout device is: /vdevice/vty@30000000
Preparing to boot Linux version 3.13.0-32-powerpc64-smp (buildd@sagari) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul )
Detected machine type: 0000000000000101
Max number of cores passed to firmware: 512 (NR_CPUS = 1024)
Calling ibm,client-architecture-support... not implemented
command line: ro ramdisk_size=8192 file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet -- console=ttyS0
memory layout at init:
  memory_limit : 0000000000000000 (16 MB aligned)
  alloc_bottom : 0000000003e38000
  alloc_top    : 0000000010000000
  alloc_top_hi : 00000005c0000000
  rmo_top      : 0000000010000000
  ram_top      : 00000005c0000000
instantiating rtas at 0x000000000f7d7000... done
Querying for OPAL presence... not there.
prom_hold_cpus: skipped
copying OF device tree...
Building dt strings...
Building dt structure...
Device tree strings 0x0000000003f39000 -> 0x0000000003f3a22c
Device tree struct  0x0000000003f3b000 -> 0x0000000003f53000
 -&gt; smp_release_cpus()
spinning_secondaries = 15
 &lt;- smp_release_cpus()
 &lt;- setup_system()
```

Note that I successfully installed Fedora 19 few months ago on the same server using the boot `linux vnc` and then continued on another PC using vnc, but I don't know how to do this on the Ubuntu boot prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
The correct yaboot command is:

```
install-powerpc64 console=hvsi0
```

because power5 uses `/dev/hvsi0` for console, not `/dev/tty0`.
Using this, Ubuntu was installed flawlessly. I don't think that Ubuntu yaboot supports vnc installation though.

Answer (score 0):

A eServer aren't exactly the same as a PowerPC.  So if your trying to install it on a eServer (aka Power5) then it isn't supported and you would get that error.  However if you have a PowerPC then it should work without issue.  See below.

IBM support for Ubuntu actually started with IBM Power8 and officially is only support on power8 and future power systems. The support actually required changes to the fsp. The older Power system however will support Redhat and SUSE.

See the links below

IBM
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistros.htm?lang=en
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistrospower7.htm?lang=en

Ubuntu
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/models/?vendors=IBM